# hardhat compile, solc, bytecode and missing library references

Tags: solidity, solc, hardhat

I am looking [Sushiswap](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap) Hardhat compilation output. Specifically, [UniswapV2Router02](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/4fdfeb7dafe852e738c56f11a6cae855e2fc0046/contracts/uniswapv2/UniswapV2Router02.sol) output.

`UniswapV2Router02` router refers to `UniswapV2Library`. However, there are no link references for this library in the generated compilation artefact:

```
  "bytecode": "0x60c06...",
  "deployedBytecode": "0x60806...",
  "linkReferences": {},
  "deployedLinkReferences": {}
```

There are no symbolic references in the bytecode either.

How solc / Hardhat knows to "link" `UniswapV2Library` when the contract is deployed? Is there a deterministic address for the `UniswapV2Library` library? Is the library inlined? Do the library contract need to be deployed separately, or is it somehow done automatically in some of the Hardhat steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solc the responsible. All functions in `UniswapV2Library` are marked as internal, so they are inlined in the contract calling them.

Similar thing used to happen with SafeMath, internal functions are inlined. The only functions requiring a link are external or public.